# recreating returned variables under the same name

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

I have a function that returns an array of variables. The variables it returns vary depending on what it needs to return. For example one time it could `return array($pet,$color);` and another time it could `return array($height,$width,$table);`

On the receiving end I want to make these variables available. If I knew I was expecting `$pet and $color`, I could do something like

```
list($pet, $color) = myfunction();
```

but I don't know what the function is going to return each time. So is there a way I could still recreate these variables under the same names when I receive the function output?

**Edit: I was hoping to not have to do it by defining an associative array that has the name of the variable saved as a string in addition to the variable itself.**

Comment: How does the _function_ know what it's going to return?

Comment: @Tim Well it does return one constant thing: an array. The contents of the array depend on the function logic and that's why it varies. That's why I put the variables in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the function return an associative array, eg

```
return array(
    'height' => $height,
    'width'  => $width,
    'table'  => $table
);
```

If so, you can then use the [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to bring each entry into the current scope's symbol table

Comment: Wow, never heard of extract! That's pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use associative arrays instead, so entries will have fixed names associated with them:

array('height'=>$height, 'width'=>$width, 'table'=>$table)